# Python multi-conditional if statement with action for each conditional

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to check multiple bools and do something if they are all true, but also do something for each that is true. 
Essentially combining the following into one:

```py
# I want to combine this:
if funcA() and funcB() and funcC():
   #do something

#with these:
if funcA():
   #do A's something

if funcB():
   #do B's something

if funcC():
   #do C's something
```

All the functions above just return bools.

I'm looking for a more efficient (line wise) way of doing this.

Comment: Are A, B, and C guaranteed to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: A way to do this in less lines. I'm already checking the values of each function in the first statement, so surely there's a way that doesn't require me checking them all individually again.

Comment: and A, B and C can return any combination of bools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to put A, B, & C's code inside the functions themselves

```
def funcA():
   if random.choice([True, False]):
       print("doing A's something")
       return True
```

Then i can call each function and not use its return value, and then do my conditional check afterwards.

```
funcA()
funcB()
funcC()

if funcA() and funcB() and funcC():
   print("do something if all true")
```

Comment: Doubt anyone will see this, but better solution was to put the result of each function in a list and then use `all()` to check if all returned true. This means the functions only have to be called once each.